# Samsung Galaxy S phone USB device recognized by host VirtualBox OS but undefined in guest OS

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s, windows, usb-drivers, virtualization

My phone model is

> Samsung Galaxy
>
> S SGH-T959

When plugged in via USB cable, the phone is well recognized by Windows as below snapshot.

[image]

[image]

But when I select the `Samsung phone` device from `Device` menu of the  VirtualBox guest OS window as below snapshot, the device is not regconized after Windows try to auto update driver for that device :(

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Is the USB icon on the VirtualBox enabled on the guest OS.

If that's disabled, the USB on the host side will not pass it through the guest, this requires the handset plugged in host side.

It's a small icon on the bottom of the VM window, near the hard disk where it shows blinking activity? Click on that, to enable USB pass-through.

<sup>Are you intending to flash the device from within a VM?</sup>

Comment: Yes the icon is flashing @t0mm13b. And yes I do ^^ You got my intention in flashing the device from a VM since the flasing tool(s) available on the internet are full of scary trojan/virus :-(

Comment: @NamG.VU All I can say is, be careful in flashing a handset from within a VM. Sure USB pass through are somewhat better than what it used to be, but there is a risk involved, be better off to flash it from the host instead for better stability in USB commmunications.